# Como importar dados da internet para o excel vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Estou tentando baixar uma tabela do site: "http://www.scoutscartola.com/mercado", e eu já até que "consegui". Mas tem um problema no meu código. Eu quero que o usuário defina o time. Isso é feito pela seleção em uma combo box no site, pois bem, eu até mudo o dado da combo box, porém a tabela não é atualizada.

Abaixo o código para que vocês vejam do que estou falando.

```
Sub navega_cartola_fc()

   Dim ie As Object
   Dim Nome As String

   Set ie = New InternetExplorer

   Nome = "Botafogo"

   ie.navigate "http://www.scoutscartola.com/mercado"

   ie.Visible = True

   While ie.Busy: Wend

   For Each obj In ie.Document.all.Item("data[filtro_time]")

        If obj.innerText = Nome Then

            obj.Selected = True

        End If

   Next obj

   Dim r, c As Integer
   Dim elemCol As Object

   Set elemCol = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")

   Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 3)

   For r = 0 To elemCol(0).Rows.Length - 1

     For c = 0 To elemCol(0).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1

       ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCol(0).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText

     Next c

   Next r
```

Após ativar corretamente esta combo box, o excel deveria mudar também outra combo box na parte inferior do site (uma que diz quantos jogadores deseja filtra, pois essa vem por padrão 25 e eu gostaria de por pelo menos 100, para não correr o risco de ficar jogador de fora da pesquisa)...

Alguém saberia o que fazer neste caso?
Pois todos os materiais que vejo, a pessoa muda a combo box assim como fiz, porém tem um botão no próprio site que "atualiza" os dados. Mas neste meu caso não tem botão de atualização, a atualização é feita assim que o time e selecionado na combo box - pelo site -  e isso não ocorre quando faço pelo vba.

Comment: Bem vindo ao site. Foram feitas algumas edições na sua pergunta, com a finalidade de melhorar a formatação e facilitar a leitura.

Comment: Obrigado. Até tinha identação. mas ao copiar colar não veio. outro erro esta no primeiro for onde diz : "If obj.innerText = Link Then" não deveria de = Link e sim = Nome só que ainda não aprendi a editar

Comment: Apenas selecionei o texto e cliquei na formatação de código. Mas você é livre para editar a pergunta. Basta clicar em "editar". Aproveita e da uma olhada nas ferramentas que aparecem na parte superior do campo onde você digita o texto. Elas vão te auxiliar a formatar o conteúdo da melhor forma possivel. E Feliz 2017 :D.

Comment: É... Já estou começando a entender como funciona a edição. Obrigado pela dica. E feliz 2017 pra você também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o seguinte código:

```
Sub navega_cartola_fc()

  Dim ieApp As Object
  Dim Nome As String

  Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

  Nome = "Botafogo"

  ieApp.navigate "http://www.scoutscartola.com/mercado"

  ieApp.Visible = True
  While ieApp.Busy: Wend

  'atualiza a pagina depois de preencher os valores dos campos a procurar
  Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
  Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

  'altera o valor da combobox
  Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
  Set ObjAaa =ieDoc.getElementById("tmercado_length").getElementsByTagName("select")(0)
  Dim evt As Object
  Set evt = ieDoc.createEvent("htmlevents")
  evt.initEvent "change", True, False

  ObjAaa.Value = 100
  'Vai selecionar este valor -> <option value="-1">1000</option>
  'Se quiseres outro valor altera consoante o valor do "value"
  ObjAaa.dispatchEvent evt

  '<<<< new update >>>>
  Set ieDoc1 = ieApp.Document
  Set ObjAaaTime = ieApp.Document.all.Item("data[filtro_time]")(0)
  Dim evt1 As Object
  Set evt1 = ieDoc.createEvent("htmlevents")
  evt1.initEvent "change", True, False

  ObjAaaTime.Value = Nome
  'Vai selecionar este valor -> <option value="botafogo">Botafogo</option>
  'Se quiseres outro valor altera consoante o valor do "value"
  'se vais fornecer este valor pelo excel deves de criar uma espécie de uma lista fixa com todos os valores possíveis
  ObjAaaTime.dispatchEvent evt1

  'volta a atualizar a página
  Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
  Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

  Dim r, c As Integer
  Dim elemCol As Object

  Set elemCol = ieApp.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")

  Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 3)

  For r = 0 To elemCol(0).Rows.Length - 1
      For c = 0 To elemCol(0).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1
          ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 1, c + 1) =elemCol(0).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
      Next c
  Next r

  ieApp.Quit

  Set elemCol = Nothing
  Set ieApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: Boa tarde jsantos1991. O código conseguiu alterar a combo box referente a quantidade de jogadores, porém não "ativou" a combo box referente ao time.  Você saberia como fazer isso? Lembrando que o time é definido pela variável Nome, que neste meu exemplo esta travada no time Botafogo, mas que posteriormente irei vincular a alguma célula.

Comment: Em: "Dim evt As Object" aparece o erro => Declaração duplicada no escopo atual. mudei para Dim evt1 As Object resolveu. Porém em: ObjAaaTime.Value = "botafogo" deu o erro => A variáve do bloco ou a variável do bloco 'with' não foi definida.

Comment: Acabei de conseguir aqui. O que devo fazer agora? edito tua dica pondo o código que resolveu ou edito a minha pergunta? Dizendo que a mesma já foi solucionada. Sou novo aqui e não conheço os procedimentos.

Comment: Então irei editar o teu, pondo o código final. Ai é ate bom que você da uma olhada se fiz alguma ignorância em relação a programação vba.

Comment: Esta ai como ficou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda jsantos1991. Estou a 5 dias quebrando a cabeça nisso.